# Typescript error in Storybook 3.4.6 using ts-loader

Tags: typescript, webpack, ts-loader, storybook

I am trying to run Storybook 3.4.6 with Typescript. Currently I am trying to make it work using `ts-loader`. Whenever I try running `yarn storybook`, i get the error:

```
Module build failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'afterCompile' 
of undefined at successfulTypeScriptInstance
```

#### Some info on my setup:

**.storybook/config.js**

```
...
function loadStories() {
    const req = require.context('../src', true, /^.*\.stories\.tsx$/)
    req.keys().forEach(filename => req(filename))
}
...
```

**.storybook/webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require("path");
const TSDocgenPlugin = require("react-docgen-typescript-webpack-plugin");
module.exports = (baseConfig, env, config) => {
    config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
        loader: require.resolve("ts-loader")
    });
    config.plugins.push(new TSDocgenPlugin()); // optional
    config.resolve.extensions.push(".ts", ".tsx");
    return config;
};
```

**Folder structure**

```
├── .storybook
└── src
    └── components
        └── Button
            ├── Button.tsx
            └── Button.stories.tsx
```

**Storybook version and affected addons**

```
"@storybook/addon-actions": "^3.4.6",
"@storybook/addon-info": "^3.4.6",
"@storybook/addon-links": "^3.4.6",
"@storybook/react": "^3.4.6",
"react-docgen-typescript-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.0",
"ts-loader": "^4.0.0",
"tslint": "^5.9.1",
"typescript": "^2.9.1",
"webpack": "^4.11.1",       
"webpack-cli": "^2.1.3"
```

Screenshot:
[image: screen shot 2018-06-07 at 09 22 03]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out Storybook v3.4.6. only supports Webpack 3. So, to be able to use Webpack 4, i upgraded Storybook to v4 (alpha), and that solved my issue.

```
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^3.4.6",
    "@storybook/addon-info": "^3.4.6",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^3.4.6",
    "@storybook/addons": "^3.4.6",
    "@storybook/react": "4.0.0-alpha.8",
    "ts-loader": "^4.3.1",
    "tslint": "^5.9.1",
    "typescript": "^2.9.1",
    "webpack": "^4.11.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.1.3"
```

Comment: You could've also downgraded `ts-loader` to some version `3.x`